# help me create a vim snippet (snipmate)

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate

Let's say I have the following snippet:

```
snippet divt
    <div id="${1:div_id}">
        ${2:'some text'}
    </div>
```

So when I type divt and hit tab twice "'some text'" should be selected, and when I hit tab once more I would like "some text" to be selected (witoutht single quotes). How can I do it?

Edit 1: Thanks for your answers. Probably this example makes more sense:

> ```
> snippet divt
>     <div ${1:id="${2:div_id}"}>
>     </div>
> ```

Sometimes I want a div without an id, so i need to be able to delete the id="div_id" altogether. Sometimes i'd like to have an id, so that i can change div_id part only.

Comment: I suggest you create two snippets divt and divtq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently on a promoting trip for [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) which I am maintaning. The snippet that does precisely that looks like this for UltiSnips:

```
snippet divt "div" b
<div ${1:id="${2:div_id}"}>
</div>
endsnippet
```

UltiSnips also comes with a converter script for snipMate snippets, so switching should be painless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found out about UltiSnips recently. It's great.

Answer (score 1):

SnipMate unfortunately doesn't support nested placeholders but, as per @Benoit's advice, you could use another snippet while editing the second placeholder. Be sure to bring a spinning top with you, though.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with `some text` vs `'some text'` — both being treated exactly the same way in this context by every html parser on earth — but I would achieve that with a simple

```
snippet div
    <div id="${1:div_id}">
        ${2}
    </div>
```

and simply typing either

```
some text
```

or

```
'
```

which would be expanded to (`|` is the caret)

```
'|'
```

thanks to delimitMate or any other similar plugin then

```
'some text'
```

Or maybe use surround to change

```
some text|
```

into

```
'some text'
```

by typing

```
<Esc>v2bS'
```

With Surround you can also start with

```
some text
```

select it with

```
v2e
```

or something similar and type

```
S'
```

to add the quotes then select the line with

```
V
```

and type

```
S<div id="div_id">
```

to obtain

```
<div id="div_id">
    'some text'
</div>
```

or do it the other way or... someone has to write a blog post with ALL the possible ways to achieve a given task in Vim.